# How I can move last line of a file first?

Tags: unix

I have a file which contains 3 lines in this order:

```
bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_off.vtran"
bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_on.vtran"
bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_sanity_dft.vtran"
```

I have to execute all lines in unix command line one by one in this order:

```
bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_sanity_dft.vtran"
bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_off.vtran"
bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_on.vtran"
```

How can I rearrange & execute all 3 commands using a single command line?

I have tried as you suggest:

```
line1: echo start 
line2: bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_sanity_dft.vtran"
line3: echo hello 
line4: bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_off.vtran" 
line5: echo bye 
line6: bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_on.vtran" 
line7: echo end
```

It still execute only line1 & line2. Exit there after..

Comment: you can use `head -1` and `tail +1` to get the first line and the rest of the file; then you only have to append both to a newly created file in the proper order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of `tac` (concatenate and print files in reverse), print the first item at the end and then reverse back:

```
tac file | awk 'NR==1 {line=$0; next} 1; END{print line}' | tac
```

#### Update

> Thank you so much fedorqui answering for my first part of question. I
>   can redirect the output of your command to a file & source it from the
>   command line to execute one by one. instead Can you step forward and
>   suggest a way to do it in a single command (without redirecting to a
>   file & source)

You can pipe to bash:

```
tac file | awk 'NR==1 {line =$0; next} 1; END{print line}' | tac | bash
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file
1
2
3

$ tac file | awk 'NR==1 {line =$0; next} 1; END{print line}' | tac
3
1
2
```

By pieces:

- reverse

  ```
  $ tac file
  3
  2
  1
  ```
- print first item at the end:

  ```
  $ tac file | awk 'NR==1 {line=$0; next} 1; END{print line}'
  2
  1
  3
  ```
- reverse:

  ```
  $ tac file | awk 'NR==1 {line =$0; next} 1; END{print line}' | tac
  3
  1
  2
  ```