# How to copy unique columns from multiple txt files to form one new txt file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

I have three .txt files (tab separated)

```
FileA.txt
Data_ID sample_ID
2253791 20481
2253793 20483
2253798 20488
```

FileB.txt

```
Subject_ID        age    sex     smok
1869793 11      2       1
1869585 7       1       3
1870238 9       2       1
```

FileC.txt

```
Subject_ID        Data_ID
1869793 2253798
1869585 2253793
1870238 2253791
```

I want to merge these three files in a way that my `output.txt` contain all the unique columns of three files like following

```
Subject_ID Data_ID sample_ID  age sex smok
1869793 2253798 20481 11      2       1
1869585 2253793 20483 7       1       3
1870238 2253791 20488 9       2       1
```

I have tried `paste` like following but its not working. Where i am doing wrong? Is there some other solution with paste or `awk` too?

```
paste <(awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' FileA.txt)\
<(awk '{print $1}' FileC.txt)\  
 <(awk '{print $2"\t"$3"\t"$4"}' FileC.txt)\ 
> output.txt
```

Comment: You want just the column names?

Comment: I have editted in question to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### output without order or any relationship:

1, `$4"}'` there is a extra `"`, should remove it in your command.

2, the last **FileC.txt** should change **FileB.txt**.

3, the paste `following but its not working`'s code maybe has some error format? could your upload a screenshot for that ?

4, just only merge the column without something relationship judgement ?

If yes, try this( only some format fixed by your code to one-line ):

```
paste <(awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' FileC.txt) <(awk '{print $2}' FileA.txt)  <(awk '{print $2"\t"$3"\t"$4}' FileB.txt) > output.txt
```

get what you want before me edit your question:

```
$ cat output.txt 
Subject_ID  Data_ID sample_ID   age sex smok
1869793 2253798 20481   11  2   1
1869585 2253793 20483   7   1   3
1870238 2253791 20488   9   2   1
```

##### output with order and the relationship:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 <(join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k2 FileC.txt) <(sort -k1 FileA.txt) | sort -k2) <(sort -k1 FileB.txt) | tac | awk 'NR==1 {line=$0; next} 1; END{print line}' | tac
```

get the output:

```
Subject_ID Data_ID sample_ID age sex smok
1869585 2253793 20483 7 1 3
1869793 2253798 20488 11 2 1
1870238 2253791 20481 9 2 1
```

1, use `join` to merge two file's line by the same column which had been `sort`.

2, use [`tac file | awk 'NR==1 {line=$0; next} 1; END{print line}' | tac`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833588/how-i-can-move-last-line-of-a-file-first) move the header to the top.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful answer for beginners like me.